# how to setup prose.io to edit md files without github?

Tags: github, jekyll, prose

[prose.io](http://prose.io) is great for editing markup files hosted at Github. But how can I use prose.io (or its source) to edit files lying in my private git repo, without the need to push my markup files to Github repos?

I'm thinking of setting up jekyll based static site generator server, with git and jekyll, in order to deploy static websites with jekyll, and edit their content over the web with prose.io, but without Github and without any local install.

Comment: That site specifically says, "Prose is a content editor for GitHub designed for managing websites", and then prompts the user to authorize via GitHub before it does anything else. I doubt it's meant to support anything else.

Comment: Yes, but since it's open source, I'm searching the way how to modify this, i.e. change the way of authorization.

Comment: My mistake, I did a very quick search earlier and wasn't able to find its source code.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the scope associated with the requested OAuth in [`app/views/nav.js`](https://github.com/prose/prose/blob/v1.1.13/app/views/nav.js#L26-L29):

```js
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(_.template(this.template, {
    login: config.site + '/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + config.id + '&scope=repo'
  }, { variable: 'data' }));
```

A scope "repo" is suppose to be enough to access public repos as well as private repos.
See [GitHub OAuth scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).